# Zend Backend URL Posting

Tags: zend-framework, paypal

I am doing Paypal IPN with Zend Framework and I would like to sent the verification url of ipn. How can I submit the back end request in Zend?

For example:

```
 $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
 $formData = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

     $url="www.sandbox.paypal.com?cmd=_notify-validate&transaction_subject=Zhopenemr Plan Subscription&txn_type=subscr_payment&payment_date=04:02:32 Mar 16, 2012 PDT&subscr_id=I-XFD23RR8DT6G&last_name=T P&residence_country=US&pending_reason=echeck&item_name=Zhopenemr Plan Subscription&payment_gross=4169.90&mc_currency=USD&business=tpprad_1211426184_biz@hotmail.com&payment_type=echeck&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&verify_sign=AGkW.2d.KC8Af-bSXQHFoo4g-LvfAmXI1BIIEMPHZZem9-oQOwopoG4i&payer_status=verified&test_ipn=1&payer_email=tpprad_1211426414_per@hotmail.com&txn_id=98J32260FL8930534&receiver_email=tpprad_1211426184_biz@hotmail.com&first_name=Pradeep&payer_id=LVQGVA8WRESRN&receiver_id=U6AEZTRXA6L4U&payment_status=Pending&mc_gross=4169.90&charset=windows-1252&notify_version=3.4&ipn_track_id=ff7d0a9a6f2d2";



     $request = new zHTTPRequest($url, HTTP_METH_GET);
    // $request->setRawPostData($xml);
     $request->send();
     $response = $request->getResponseBody();

    $ipnval="";
    foreach($formData as $key=>$value){
          $ipnval.= "".$key." = ".$value." <br>";
    }
```

I want to submit the $url to paypal and to verify the status. How can I do this in the back end?

```
 $request = new zHTTPRequest($url, HTTP_METH_GET);
    // $request->setRawPostData($xml);
     $request->send();
     $response = $request->getResponseBody();
```

This statement can do it with simple php. How can this work with Zend?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            // check the payment_status is Completed
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // process payment
        } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
        }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}
exit;
```